# how to use __eval in preprocessor of jmeter

Tags: testing, jmeter, jsr223

I am using a faker.jar plugin to generate random data inside json file

The JSON file is like

```js
{
    "name" = "${__BeanShell(new com.github.javafaker.Faker().name().fullName())}"
 "id" = "${__BeanShell(new com.github.javafaker.Faker().IdNumber())}"
}
```

and in jmeter i am using a http sampler

[image]

This is working fine, but now i want to evaluate the request with response, so i want to save the request body inside a variable and pass that variable to http request and then use post process to evaluate request against response, but i am unable to use ${__eval()} function inside preprocessor.

How to fix that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) as a child of the HTTP Request sampler
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   vars.put('foo', sampler.getArguments().getArgument(0).getValue())
   ```

   3 That's it, the PreProcessor will fetch the body data from the HTTP Request sampler and store it into `${foo}` JMeter Variable.

---

Be aware that [according to JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) you should be using [__groovy() function](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) instead of __Beanshell() so consider amending your JSON file on next available opportunity.

Be also informed that JMeter provides some built-in functions allowing generation of random values i.e. [__Random()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random), [__RandomString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__RandomString), [__UUID()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__UUID), etc. so you might even discard your 3rd-party library as JMeter built-in functions provide better performance.